# choropleth map using plotly express

Tags: express, geolocation, label, plotly-python, geo

I am trying to make choropleth map using plotly express , i want static label of states in my chart but i am not sure how to do that.

Below is the sample data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVaDD.jpg)

here is my code

Import plotly.express as px

fig=px.choropleth(choropleth,locations="USA-states",scope="usa",animation_frame="Year-month",animation_group="State",color="Bucket"
fig.show()

Comment: Hi. please  read  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I insert the data

Comment: use code formatting tool, while editing your question. Read [help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), there is a section for tables